# Why is my R squared wrong

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have this sample data:

```
data <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
data[, 1] = c(3, 1.008991)
data[, 2] = c(4, 0.9981358)
data[, 3] = c(5, 1.000626)
data <- data/norm(data)

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.4999478 0.6665971 0.8332464
[2,] 0.1681476 0.1663386 0.1667536
```

Using Ransac I got this line equation (where first index is b, second is a)

```
result <- c(0.1735747, -0.0108552)
```

Now, here's my R squared calculation ([using wikipedia equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions))

```
y_ <- sum(data[2,])/length(data[1,])
f <- function(x) result[2]*x+result[1]
SStot <- sum( (data[2,]-y_)^2 )
SSreg <- sum( (f(data[1,])-y_)^2 )
SSres <- sum( (data[2,]-f(data[1,]))^2 )
R2 <- 1 - (SSres/SStot)
```

The result of R2 is `-1.753875` which is incorrect (afaik). [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20regression%20%280.4999478%2C0.1681476%29%2C%20%280.6665971%2C0.1663386%29%2C%20%280.8332464%2C0.1667536%29) gives me `0.540996`. What do I do wrong? I expect R2 from interval <0, 1>.

Comment: it doesn't look like you did anything wrong, you just have bad coefficients.  The fact that ssres > sstot is telling you that your line is worse that just fitting a horizontal line through `mean(data[2,])`

Comment: you can compare the coefs you have there to ones R would give you, `summary(lm(y~x,data=data.frame(y=data[2,], x=data[1,])))`